# Change a php file path in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, path, directory

I am working on a wordpress plugin, I have an external php file that I need to use It should be placed in the Wp directory "http://localhost/forever/"
(where my wp files are uploaded).

For some reason I need to put this php file in an other folder but it should act like it's in Wp directory like changing its real path.

Comment: If you are developing WordPress plugin, why not put it in your own plugin folder?

Comment: you should create a independent plugin . I mean you should upload this file in your plugin folder.

Comment: Becuz in the plugin folder it dont work , it should be placed in wp directory to return wp data to the plugin .